# Titanium app not opening android N

Tags: appcelerator-titanium

Appcelerator application is not opening after installation. I tried one android module which was invoked in index.js to check if device datetime was enabled.When i commented this module reference from tiapp.xml, it worked. But i need this module. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Titanium SDK are you using? If we consider that you are using SDK 6.0 and above, then for Android modules, you need to re-build them with Titanium SDK 6.0 to make it compatible. For this reason if you remove the module it is working fine. Can you rebuild the module using the updated SDK and confirm.

Comment: if not just try compiling using 5.4.1 or lower SDK. else from SDK 6.0.0 above all android modules should be compiled with the newer SDKs only.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause is that Camera,Location,Storage,Calendar permissions are not getting set on app launch. Once i enable them manually via device app settings its working. I tried to set these permissions via example in 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android Permissions section but not getting set. Please advise how to set permissions in Android N